# SyntaxError in FoodTablesController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im working on a food composition table using RoR. When I try to view the table on localhost I get the following error

> :/Users/RubymineProjects/FoodDBScript/app/controllers/food_tables_controller.rb:72:
>   syntax error, unexpected ',' ...ID, :Food_Item, :Edible_part_%,
>   :Water_g, :Kilojoules_kj, :K... ... ^

This is part of my food_tables_controller.rb

```
       class FoodTablesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_food_table, only: [:show, :edit, :update,     :destroy]

     # GET /food_tables
   # GET /food_tables.json
   def index
    if params[:food_item].nil?
     @food_tables = FoodTable.all
    else
     @food_tables = FoodTable.where("Food Item LIKE ?", '%' +    params[:food_item] + '%')
    end
    end

   # GET /food_tables/1
   # GET /food_tables/1.json
   def show
   end

   # GET /food_tables/new
   def new
    @food_table = FoodTable.new
  end

  # GET /food_tables/1/edit
 def edit
 end

  # POST /food_tables
 # POST /food_tables.json
 def create
   @food_table = FoodTable.new(food_table_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @food_table.save
    format.html { redirect_to @food_table, notice: 'Food table was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @food_table }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @food_table.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
   end
 end

 # PATCH/PUT /food_tables/1
 # PATCH/PUT /food_tables/1.json
 def update
   respond_to do |format|
  if @food_table.update(food_table_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @food_table, notice: 'Food table was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @food_table }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @food_table.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
 end

 # DELETE /food_tables/1
# DELETE /food_tables/1.json
 def destroy
   @food_table.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to food_tables_url, notice: 'Food table was  successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
 # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_food_table
  @food_table = FoodTable.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def food_table_params
  params[:food_table]
     end
  end
```

Comment: Please format your code snippet.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I tried copy the code and running its running. No syntax error. Either specify the question or can be closed

Answer (score 0):

You don't have syntax error in provided snippet.

But given your error message: you shouldn't use `:Edible_part_%`, that's not a correct name for symbol.

Use `:edible_part_percentage` instead.

Though you could use `:Edible_part_percentage` with first upper-cased letter, and even `:'Edible_part_%'` with quotes as symbol names, you will find it more useful to follow Rails naming conventions as well.